# how can I fetch alarms in related Asset to special Device by thingsboard library in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, entity, alarm, thingsboard

I set the device profile in web UI of ThingsBoard to create alarms when some telemetries are out of the accepted range.
My device is related to the special Asset.
In the web UI of ThingsBoard, I can see alarms in both entities of Asset and Device, but in my Flutter app, I can't fetch alarms by asset Id.
I use from `tbClient.getAlarmService().getAllAlarms(alarmQuery)`, I set `alarmQuery` as follow:

```
alarmQuery=AlarmQuery(TimePageLink(10,0,null,SortOrder('createdTime',Direction.DESC)),fetchOriginator:true);
alarmQuery.searchStatuse=AlarmSearchStatuse.ACTIVE;
alarmQuery.affectedEntityId=myEntityId;
```

When I run the above program, all alarms of all assets and devices are fetched, While I expected only myEntityId alarms to be displayed.
Please let me know, how can I fetch only alarms of special Asset.